# setting Hex character for page break in Notepad

Tags: notepad

I have set Hexa character Hex(12) in program output for page break to a old printer alignment. When open the output text file with Notepad, the Hex'oc' will show as small male symbol (with small circal and a plus sign bottom). But some Notepad show as small square box for the same page break symbol.

The printing alignment is OK when using Notepad with small male symbol. However the printing alignment is not OK when using Notepad with small square box symbol.

BTW, I am using MS Window XP Pro version 2002 service pack 3.

Can anyboby help me on this ??

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Nippey, There is same output text file with Hax(12) sign using same printer and driver. However one Win XP's PC give good alignment, but try on another Win XP's PC give alignment out. Then, we found that the PC gave good alignment is Notepad showing page break as female sign, The PC gave alignment out is Notepad showing page break as small square sign. How to change page break symbol from small square sign to female sign ?

Answer (score 0):

You mean this ♀ "female sign"?

The may be editors which switch to unicode whn discovering such symbols. Then your printer might get different data.

Another reason is the type of printer and driver:
There are drivers which just send what dots have to be drawn on the paper, others just send the text an dthe printer does it itself.

You wrote Notepad twice, do you mean the same native windows program?
What versions does it have?
If I go on "Help" > "About" it is printed: Version 6.1.7601